# Magento Product qty replicated to all products?

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.9, product

I tried many ways to fix this issue.No luck.Please help me out guys.

When an import is run, the stock qty data for the product on the first line of the CSV is replicated for all other products in the file, regardless of what inventory data you set in the import file itself.
[image]

Comment: How are you importing your file?  Which editor did you use for creating the csv file?

Comment: @Muk Thanks for quick reply.I'm not using any specific editor to create csv.Am using ms office.And earlier the file which i'm trying to upload was working fine.

Comment: After saving the file in Ms office as csv try to open it with Notepad++ and check Qty field

Comment: @Muk ya tried same way also.evrything is ok as it in csv,i mean no changes in qty field.

Comment: How are you importing the file?

Comment: @Muk System->Import/Export->Import

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100985/discussion-between-nagendra-and-muk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution.
I've installed IMS extension in my site.In stock import `foreach()` loop
`$row = array();` was missing.After i added to my file it started working again.